# How to pass value from another table to jsonb in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables.

Table A

```
 id |       json       
----+------------------
  a | {"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.02"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.2" ...
----+------------------
 b  | {"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.32"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.47" ...
```

Table B

```
idx |  state| dir     
----+-------+----------
  1 | TX    | 123
----+-------+----------
  2 | CA    | 15
```

I want to filter table A using column temp from table B. And Table B will select base upon idx value.

I want to select value from each row when state equal to temporary table which is created from tableB using where idx is certain number

lets say idx is equal to 2. That means I can create temporary table using following sql query

```
with tempT AS(
SELECT * 
FROM tableB 
where idx = 2);
```

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
idx |  state| value     
----+-------+----------
  2 | CA    | 0.2
----+-------+----------
  2 | CA    | 0.47
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is the `json` field from table A really jsonb? It does not look that way

Comment: I have double checked. and it is jsonb. It was typing error on my part, updated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) like:

```
WITH A AS
  (SELECT 'a' AS id,
          '{"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.02"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.2"}]}'::jsonb AS json
   UNION SELECT 'b' AS id,
                '{"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.32"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.47"}]}'::jsonb AS json),
     B AS
  (SELECT 1 AS idx,
          'TX' AS state,
          123 AS dir
   UNION SELECT 2 AS idx,
                'CA' AS state,
                15 AS dir)
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT A.id,
          jsonb_array_elements(A.json->'st') AS obj
   FROM A) AS A
inner JOIN B on  B.state = obj->>'State'::text
where B.idx = 2;
```

Comment: The shorter way to provide the test data: `with a(id,json) as (values('a','{...}'::jsonb),('b','{...}')) ...`